# how to access the checkbox.click inside a list of panels using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this hierarchy, a tabcontainer(tcmain) under that a tabpanel(tpnlRaiseMRF) under that an asp panel(RaiseMRF) under that a checkbox(cbxRecNote). I want to add this function on click. I am adding like this :

> $(document).ready(function () {
>               $("#pnlRecNote").hide();
>               $("#cbxRecNote").click(function () {
>                   $("#pnlRecNote").slideToggle();
>               });
>           });

the pnlRecNote is directly under form, so its hiding. The cbxRecNote click is not getting fired(above code).
but its not working, please help me. I am very new to jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a console.log instead of the slidetoggle to see if it's being trigered? Do you get any errors when you run that?

Comment: `"I want to add this function on click."` What's `this function` referring to? Also, what click event do you want to capture?

Comment: @JSantos : no i m not getting any error.

Comment: @Rob : On checking the checkbox i want to toggle the panel.

Comment: Can you manualy run the commands on console? If you do $("#pnlRecNote").slideToggle(); does it run? Can you find your elements within console? Also try replacing $("#cbxRecNote") with $("[id$=cbxRecNote]") and do the same for other elements

Comment: @JSantos : hey $("[id$=cbxRecNote]") is working... thanks a lot.

Comment: Posted that as an answer. If you need any more help coment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your elements with $("[id$=cbxRecNote]")

Answer (score 0):

finding your checkbox is a straight forward way, just use your element's ID.

try this:

```
$("#cbxRecNote").change(function(){
// type your code here
});
```

this will take advantage of the browser's native javaScript `getElementById()` function which is the fastest way you can have.

check this live demo from here: http://jsfiddle.net/eS8eY/3/

Comment: @ElSayed : it can be accessed since its inside some other elements like tabcontainer having id (tcMain) and tabpanel having id (tpRaiseMRF).

Comment: @NayeemKhan: I know, but considering the direct usage of item's ID is much cleaner and speedy too.

Comment: @elsayed:  in that way its not working also know. remember, a tabcontainer is ajax control, under that i have a tabpanel, under which i have panel which is containing my checkbox.